# Correctly interpreting a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test and a Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interpretation, stata, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I want to confirm my understanding of the two tests referenced in the title.

Say I have data on a variable $Y$ from two groups (0 and 1), and I perform the following tests in Stata:

```
. kwallis Y, by(group)

Kruskal–Wallis equality-of-populations rank test

  +--------------------------+
  | group |   Obs | Rank sum |
  |-------+-------+----------|
  |     0 | 2,639 | 8.19e+06 |
  |     1 | 3,576 | 1.11e+07 |
  +--------------------------+

  chi2(1) =  0.035
     Prob = 0.8515

  chi2(1) with ties =  0.035
               Prob = 0.8515

. ksmirnov Y, by(group)

Two-sample Kolmogorov–Smirnov test for equality of distribution functions

Smaller group             D     p-value  
---------------------------------------
0                    0.0470       0.001
1                   -0.0314       0.050
Combined K-S         0.0470       0.002
```

From these tests do I conclude that the distributions of $Y$ for the two groups are statistically different (based on the K-S test at 5% threshold), but we cannot reject the hypothesis that the groups have the same median (based on the K-W test at 5% significance)?

How exactly should I interpret the p-values for `Smaller group` = 0 and 1?

Comment: The Wilcoxon test does not test the median but rather whether responses from one group tend to be larger than responses from the other group.  But you are otherwise on the right track.  **But** show a graph of the two empirical cumulative distribution functions and also two histograms with a large number of bins.  These will likely show that the groups differ in dispersion but not in central tendency.

Comment: @FrankHarrell This seems to be an answer to me, not just a comment.

Comment: I put it as a comment since we need to see raw data displays to really answer.

Comment: @FrankHarrell: Thank you! You've answered my question.